# not able to send dropdown list value using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In application I am using ajax to send data to back end like this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ApplicationDetails.aspx/GetMessageFromWebPage", 
    data: {
            title: $('#Content_Monitoring_Statistics_dropdownfilter option:selected').val()
          }, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data));}
    });
```

Bellow is my Drop down whose value I want to send to back end

```
   <asp:dropdownlist id="dropdownfilter" runat="server" >
     <asp:listitem text="Hits for last 24 hours" selected="True" value="last24hours"></asp:listitem>
     <asp:listitem text="Hits for last 7 days" value="last7days"></asp:listitem>
     <asp:listitem text="Hits for last year" value="lastyear"></asp:listitem>
  </asp:dropdownlist>
```

But it is not posting data back to server side.
When I remove data, it works fine but with data it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created 
Object like this

```
var selectedFilter = {}; 
selectedFilter.title = $("#Content_Monitoring_Statistics_dropdownfilter option:selected").val();
```

& passed it to data like this

```
data: JSON.stringify(selectedFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data in Json format so simply sending data won't work you need to convert data to JSON.Use JSON.stringify like this

```
data:JSON.stringify({
                title: $("#MainContent_ddlTest option:selected").val(),
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass dropdown value parameter to AJAX call, you can go for:

```
title: function () { return $("#Content_Monitoring_Statistics_dropdownfilter").val(); }
```

This works for sure.